# Quasar Unknown custom element error in unit test

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, quasar

I have a simple Vue component that uses Quasar button

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span class="count">{{ count }}</span>
    <q-btn @click="increment">Increment</q-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TestComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count += 1;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I create a unit test for it

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { Quasar, QBtn } from 'quasar';
import TestComponent from '../TestComponent';

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Quasar, { components: { QBtn } });
    wrapper = mount(TestComponent, { localVue });
  });

  it('renders the correct markup', () => {
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('<span class="count">0</span>');
  });

  // it's also easy to check for the existence of elements
  it('has a button', () => {
    expect(wrapper.contains('button')).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

**My problem:**

- If I run the test cases (`it` function) one by one at a time the test will pass. For example, remove the second `it('has a button'...)` then run the test. It'll pass. It's the same when removing the first `it('renders the correct markup'...)`
- However, If I keep all test cases then run the test. The second test case will fail with an error

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js:630
      [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <q-btn> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

      found in

      ---> <TestComponent>
             <Root>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the before-each. I saw this problem too. Can't remember what exactly fixed it but this is how I have my describe block.

```
describe('Mount Quasar', () => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue()
    localVue.use(Quasar, { components })

    const wrapper = shallowMount(Register, {
        localVue,
        stubs: ['router-link', 'router-view']
    })
    const vm = wrapper.vm

    it('passes the sanity check and creates a wrapper', () => {
        expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import quasar into either webpack, babel, or jest.

In the `jest.config.js` file

Add

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    quasar: "quasar-framework/dist/umd/quasar.mat.umd.min.js"
  },
```

Comment: With latest version it's `quasar: '<rootDir>/node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.umd.min.js'`